# real modal confirm jquery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, confirm

My question is really simple and stupid, but it's impossible for me to find an answer: I just want to replace js `confirm` with a nice dialog box.
but it seems impossible to do this simple thing in jQuery:

```
function ..... () {
    alert (1);
    confirm ( "some question" );
    alert (2);
}
```

the script shows `"some question"`, *stops and waits for user input*, then continues after.

Is it really impossible in jQuery (please do not answer with confirm plugin, pseudo modal plugin, or even deffered ... ==> they do not do the same as js `confirm`)?

And if it's impossible in jQuery, is there another way to do this?

Comment: try the [sweetalert2](http://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) its simple and nice

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. You want to change style/behavior of `confirm` dialog?

Answer (score 0):

`confirm` and `alert` depend on the browser and the underlying operating system. The browser is responsible for opening them and there is no way to style them or otherwise modify the behavior.